# Using Python to remove incomplete line from the end of a JSON formatted log file

Tags: python

I have some JSON formatted log files that I am copying to S3 so I can run Hive queries on them using Elastic Map Reduce. The script I use to copy the log files to S3 is written in Python.

Every once in a while I encounter a file with an incomplete line, typically at the end of the file. This causes any Hive queries that need that file to fail. I've been manually fixing the files by removing the bad line, but I'd like to integrate this step into my Python script to prevent these failures.

Here's an example of the type of file I'm working with:

```
{"logLine":{"browserName":"FireFox","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0"}}
{"logLine":{"browserName":"Pre","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko; Google Web Preview) Chrome/11.0.696 Safari/534.24"}}
{"logLine":{"browserName":"Internet Explorer","userAgent":"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1
```

In that case I want to remove the last line since it's incomplete. I know it's incomplete because it's missing the end of line character(s), and also because it's not valid JSON due to the missing end quote and curly braces.

Is there an easy way to identify and remove that file from the file using Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has a json module in its standard library.  It has a parser that will raise an exception if the input isn't valid JSON.  To check the last line, you could do something like

```
import json
with open('log.txt') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
try:
    json.loads(lines[-1])
except ValueError:
    with open('log.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(''.join(lines[:-1]))
```

Comment: 44 seconds too late, I was :(

Comment: ...which is what the poster asked for.

Comment: This is perfect for now. If I end up having problems with other lines I'll implement something more comprehensive, but for now this solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this example below. Note that it loads the whole file into memory, so if the file is big then you may do it by loading the file line by line.

```
import json
with open('log.txt') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

towrite = ''
for line in lines:
    try:
        towrite += json.dumps(json.loads(line)) + '\n'
    except ValueError:
        pass
with open('log.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(towrite)
```

Comment: Thanks for this approach. I had a few JSON files with corrupted lines in the middle today and was able to fix them with this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab each line and pass them through a filter function.

This function would be something like

```
def isLineComplete(line):
    return line[-1] == "}"
```

Overview:

```
myFile = ...

cleanLines = filter(isLineComplete, myFile.readlines())
```

Comment: Concept is ok, but lack of an end bracket isn't the only thing that can make it invalid json....

Comment: But it's suffice to solve the specific problems that this question posed

Comment: What about `{"logLine":{"browserName":"FireFox","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0"}`      instead of    `{"logLine":{"browserName":"FireFox","userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0"}}` (2nd bracket missing)?

Comment: from the question: and also because it's not valid JSON due to the missing end quote and *curly braces*.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can isolate lines, here is how you would check:

```
try:
    json.loads('{"logLine":{"browserName":"Internet Explorer","userAgent":"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1');
except:
    #code to remove line from file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use json.loads to try to parse every line and ignore the ones that raise an exception

```
lines = """{"logLine":{"browserName":"FireFox"}}
{"logLine":{"browserName":"Pre"}}
{"logLine":{"browserName":"Internet Explorer"
"""
cleaned = []
for line in lines.splitlines():
    try:
        json.loads(line)
    except ValueError:
        continue
    cleaned.append(line)
    print cleaned
```